# Ordering of function overloads matter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, declaration

I encountered a situation where the ordering of function overloads matters. 
I thought the cause must be the SFINAE part with the `std::enable_if` ((I additionally tested the code without the `std::enable_if`, just with templates and then the code runs, regardless the ordering of function overloads.))

I made a minimal working example out of it.

This code block works

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <bool C, typename R = void>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<C, R>::type;

template <typename T, typename R = void>
using IfIsArithmetic = EnableIf<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, R>;

template <typename S>
IfIsArithmetic<S, void> Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2, S &ret)
{
 ret = scalar1 + scalar2;
}

template <typename S>
IfIsArithmetic<S, S> Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2)
{
 S ret;
 Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
 return ret;
}

using T = float;

int main(){
  T a = 3.1;
  T b = 3.5;
  T c{Add(a, b)};
}
```

whereas the following doesn't compile (the implementations of the `Add()` functions are swapped)

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <bool C, typename R = void>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<C, R>::type;

template <typename T, typename R = void>
using IfIsArithmetic = EnableIf<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, R>;

template <typename S>
IfIsArithmetic<S, S> Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2)
{
 S ret;
 Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
 return ret;
}

template <typename S>
IfIsArithmetic<S, void> Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2, S &ret)
{
 ret = scalar1 + scalar2;
}

using T = float;

int main(){
  T a = 3.1;
  T b = 3.5;
  T c{Add(a, b)};
}
```

The compiler gives the following error

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘IfIsArithmetic<S, S> Add(const S&, const S&) [with S = float; IfIsArithmetic<S, S> = float]’:
test.cpp:28:15:   required from here
test.cpp:13:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘Add(const float&, const float&, float&)’
  Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:10:22: note: candidate: template<class S> IfIsArithmetic<S, S> Add(const S&, const S&)
 IfIsArithmetic<S, S> Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2)
                      ^~~
test.cpp:10:22: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:13:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
  Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems, that the compiler tries to use the first function overload, even though the signature doesn't align.

Maybe some of you can give me hint, to which C++ function lookup rule this issue is related!

Answer (score 3):

> It seems, that the compiler tries to use the first function overload, even though the signature doesn't align.

Exactly.

The order is important.

Compiling the body of `Add(S const &scalar1, S const &scalar2)`, the compiler don't know that, after it, will be defined an `Add()` with three arguments. So try the only `Add()` that known (at the moment) but the number of arguments doesn't match.

SFINAE, template and `using` aren't the problem: you get the same error also from

```
float Add (float const &scalar1, float const &scalar2)
{
 float ret;
 Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
 return ret;
}

void Add(float const &scalar1, float const &scalar2, float &ret)
{
 ret = scalar1 + scalar2;
}

int main(){
  float a = 3.1;
  float b = 3.5;
  float c{Add(a, b)};
}
```

If you really want to define the two argument `Add()` before the tree arguments one, you have to say the compiler, before the definition of the two arguments version of `Add()`, that a three arguments version follows; you can do this declaring (non defining) the three arguments version

```
void Add (float const &, float const &, float &);

float Add (float const &scalar1, float const &scalar2)
{
 float ret;
 Add(scalar1, scalar2, ret);
 return ret;
}

void Add(float const &scalar1, float const &scalar2, float &ret)
{
 ret = scalar1 + scalar2;
}
```

This is useful in case the two functions call each others.

In your second example, you can add the declaration of the three arguments `Add()`

```
template <typename S>
IfIsArithmetic<S, void> Add(S const &, S const &, S &);
```

before the definition of the two arguments version.

**Off Topic**

Starting from C++14, you can use `std::enable_if_t` that is defined (as far I know) exactly as your `EnableIf`.

Starting from C++17 you can also use `std::is_arithmetic_v<T>` instead of `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value`.

Comment: Mandatory standard quote https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#7

Comment: It is not so much "order is important" but "the prototype needs to come before the call site".